# Erro java - Falha ao validar a assinatura do arquivo de acionamento

Tags: java

Estou obtendo o seguinte erro ao subir a aplicação via jboss:

```
JNLPSigningException[Falha ao validar a assinatura do arquivo de acionamento. A versão assinada não corresponde à obtida por download.]
    at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDesc.checkSigningTemplate(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.checkSignedLaunchDescHelper(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.checkSignedLaunchDesc(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.checkSignedLaunchDesc(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareResources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareAllResources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Este é meu arquivo JNLP:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<jnlp codebase="http://localhost:8081/sgk/application/">
  <information>
    <title>Sistema de Gestao KSI</title>
    <vendor>KSI Solucoes Informatica Ltda.</vendor>
    <description>Sistema de Gestao KSI</description>
    <description kind="tooltip">Sistema de Gestao KSI</description>
    <homepage href="http://localhost:8081/sgk" />
    <icon href="ksi.jpg" />
  </information>
  <security>
    <all-permissions/>
  </security>
  <resources>
    <!--<j2se version="1.5+" initial-heap-size="64m" max-heap-size="128m" />-->
    <j2se version="1.5+" initial-heap-size="64m" max-heap-size="512m" />
    <jar href="sgk-shared-3.12.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" download="lazy" main="true" />
    <jar href="sgk-report-3.12.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="sgk-images-3.12.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="gem-sintegra.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="JoSQL-1.4.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="binding-1.0.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="bsf-2.3.0.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="bsh-1.3.0.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="commons-beanutils-1.7.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="commons-collections-2.1.1.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="commons-digester-1.7.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="commons-jxpath-1.2.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="commons-lang-2.4.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="commons-logging-1.0.3.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="dom4j-1.5.2.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="gentlyWEB-utils-1.1.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="hibernate3.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="icu4j_3_2.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="i18n.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="iText-2.1.7.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="jasperreports-3.7.6.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="jasperreports-fonts-3.7.6.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="JBarcodeBean.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="jcalendar.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="jcommon-1.0.15.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="jfreechart-1.0.12.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="jh.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="l2fprod-common-all.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="swingx-all-1.6.3.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="swingutil1.5.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="log4j-1.2.15.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="packer.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="poi-3.8-20120326.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="rhino-1.5-R3.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="swing-layout-1.0.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="activation.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="mail.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="jna.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="emp4j-1.0.0.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="jaxen-1.1.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="pdfsam-1.0.0-b1.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="jpedal.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="pdfsam-console-1.1.1e.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="pdfsam-jcmdline-1.0.3.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="barbecue-1.5-beta1.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="iReport-barcode.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="commons-httpclient-3.1.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="commons-codec-1.3.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="gem-sintegra-ie.jar" download="lazy" />
    <!--Sefaz-->
    <jar href="gem-nfe-schema-008e.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="gem-nfe-schema-canc-1.01.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="gem-nfe-schema-cce-1.01.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="gem-sefaz.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="gem-nfe-ws.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="gem-nfe.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="jsr173_1.0_api.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="resolver.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="xbean.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="xbean_xpath.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="xmlbeans-qname.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="xmlpublic.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="gem-cte-ws.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="gem-cte.jar" download="lazy" />
    <!--Sefaz-->
    <jar href="gem-integracao.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="jrimum-bopepo-0.2.3-DEV-20140721.032224-50-dep.jar" download="lazy" />
    <!--GUI-->
    <jar href="sam.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="jtidy-8.0.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="novaworx-syntax-0.0.7.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="SHEF.jar" download="lazy" />
    <!--GUI-->
    <!--Jboss 5.1 -->
    <jar href="jnlp-servlet.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="xalan.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="jbossall-client.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="jboss-javaee.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="slf4j-jboss-logging.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="slf4j-api.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="jbosssx-client.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="jboss-security-spi.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="jboss-logging-spi.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="jnp-client.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="jboss-aop-client.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="concurrent.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="jboss-common-core.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="jboss-aspect-jdk50-client.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="jboss-ejb3-proxy-spi-client.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="jboss-ejb3-proxy-impl-client.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="jboss-ejb3-core-client.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="jboss-ejb3-common-client.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="jboss-remoting.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="jboss-integration.jar" download="lazy" />
    <jar href="jboss-ejb3-security-client.jar" download="lazy" />
    <property name="java.naming.factory.initial" value="org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory" />
    <property name="name-ear" value="gem" />
    <property name="cliente" value="true" />
    <property name="ejb3.version" value="true" />
  </resources>
  <application-desc main-class="br.com.ksisolucoes.menu.Login"></application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

Comment: Esse `xml` ai é o código que gera o erro?

Comment: Exatamente ,,,,,